# Pipeline Artifacts with Hosted Agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible use Azure DevOps [Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts) to publish/download artifacts between separate stages using Hosted Agents? I assume it's not possible to do this as there are no state between different hosted agents.

Do we have to use self-hosted agents to share artifacts between different stages?

Comment: Do you mean in a build pipeline, consuming an artifact in different agent phases?  Like build in one agent phase and then run tests in a different agent phase?  Do you have any examples you can share of your pipeline?

Comment: Let's say a build pipeline, possibility of running the next phase on a different hosted build agent is a problem. For example, you have a Python script that you run tests in phase 1, couple of hours later you manually approve deployment of that script but you have to download exactly the same script that you tested in phase 1 from the artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is possible. when you execute the build you upload artifacts. then you start a release that pulls the same artifacts and use those to deploy whatever you are deploying

Comment: Thanks, does Azure Devops keep the artifacts somewhere on cloud, not on the build agent itself?

Comment: yes,it's being stored in the cloud. hosted agents can pull it (and your own agents as well)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that it stores all artifacts on build agents. I have checked some of the artifact articles on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/index?view=vsts) but they weren't clear for me.